# Chrome: middle mouse button overriden on certain web pages?

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, sharepoint

Normally when I click on a link in Chrome with a **middle mouse button**, the page open s in a **new tab**. I find it useful and would like it to always work that way.

But on some sites, specifically SharePoint sites I'm often working with, middle click on certain links opens the page in **the same** tab. Example can be found on this publicly available [SharePoint demo page](http://www.spsdemo.com/) when clicking on "Internet Sites" or "SharePoint resources" links with middle mouse button.

[image: Problematic buttons]

Those menu items seem like a link (they definitely have URL assigned). Why do them open in the same tab instead of a new one, when middle clicked? Can this behavior be changed in Chrome's settings or using some addon?

Comment: I didn't know about the MMB open new tab function til I saw someone do it a few months back. I have (and still do) always used *CTRL + left click*, which also opens a new tab. I imagine this'll have the same result, but give it a go

Comment: And CTRL+left is new to me :) This seems however to have exactly the same result as MMB click - usually works, but on some links does not

Comment: similar: http://superuser.com/questions/266493/middle-clicking-a-link-on-chrome-sometimes-also-switches-the-current-tab-to-the?rq=1

Comment: @golimar: just what I was looking for, but couldn't find :) 'Middle button new tab' extension does the job. I guess my question can be marked as duplicate in this situation.

Comment: found it in "Related", bottom right corner of this page